# Compare Directory and File removing equals from Directory

Tags: powershell

This is the code I am trying to execute

```
$objDir = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\"
$objFile = Get-Content "C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt"
$matches = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $objFile -DifferenceObject $objDir -Property       Name,Length -excludedifferent -includeequal)  
foreach ($file in $matches)
{
    Remove-Item C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\$($file.Name)
}
```

All items that are equal in directory and txt file I want to delete from the directory will this code do that?

Comment: is that process.txt file just a list of file names? If so you could do something as simple as `$Files = GC C:\Isers\Bruce\Process.txt;GCI C:\Users\Bruce\Serena | ?{$Files -contains $_.Name} | Remove-Item $_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you *should* do without seeing the format of the data in **process.txt**, but I can tell you definitively that invoking **Compare-Object** on the results of **Get-ChildItem** and **Get-Content** can't possibly work, because the former returns an array of FileInfo objects and the latter retuns an array of strings (or just a string, if the file has only one line).

**Compare-Object** is intended primarily to compare sets of objects of the same type, though it can be used to compare sets of objects that have common property names. However, in the latter case the properties need to have the same type of information, not just the same names, in order for the comparison to be meaningful.

There's no way for it to guess what content in the strings in **$objFile** to compare to properties of the FileInfo objects in **$objDir**. The only property name these object types have in common is **Length**, but any matches on that property would be meaningless (and very unlikely) coincidences, because they have completely different meanings—the number of characters in the string, and the size of the file in bytes, respectively.

How you *should* do it depends on what kind of data you have in **process.txt**. If it's just a list of filenames, then it's as simple as

```powershell
foreach ($file in (Get-Content 'C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt')) {
  Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\$file"
}
```

If it's a CSV file containing the name and size of each file, then you'd use **Import-Csv** rather than **Get-Content**, to import the data into an array of objects with properties you can compare to the directory listing, but I'd need to see some sample data before getting specific.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.